# How to set-up Appium-webdriverIO-mocha tests for iOS & Android ReactNativeApps on BitRise and Browserstack

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, bitrise

We have UI tests for reactive Apps(iOS & Android) written in Appium-WebDriverIO/Mocha. 
The tests code sits in a separate folder inside the development code but shares same package.json & scripts.

[image]

- We are planning to run tests on
  A) Browserstack (for which we'll separately upload the build (.ipa & .apk)
  B) On BitRise platform

Does Bitrise support Appium wdio tests

Any sample specifications?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use the BrowserStack API ( https://www.browserstack.com/automate/rest-api ) from bitrise.io, e.g. from a Script step. That's probably the best option right now.

Comment: Thanks @ViktorBenei . Also could we use 'browserstack-upload' plugin on Bitrise? https://www.bitrise.io/integrations/steps/browserstack-upload

Comment: Ohh I didn't know we had a step for that already - but sure, when there's a step prefer to use that instead of writing your own scripts ;)